# Linked POST INSPECTOR giving 404 - React APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linkedin-api, social-media

I'm using React app for web development and there is a concept called "share company profile". While sharing the URL it shows something went wrong and in the LinkedIn post inspector it show like below: [image: Link Inspector] But on Facebook it works fine since it's a React app. I have placed all meta and `OG` tags in `index.html` itself.

while giving the base url in inspector its working fine but with params like `/company/IN-Gowtham-28/` not working

Answer (score 2):

If that is a valid URL and your app is a SPA (single page app) made with react, the only thing I can think of is your default redirection. Let me explain:

A react SPA creates only 1 page (/index.html) which includes your entire app, including the router and subsequent pages. so if you try to load /another/page/ that will return a 404 as there's no HTML file at the location. In order to avoid that, your web server should redirect all HTML requests to /index.html. depending on your server or hosting of choice there are several ways to do that. from there, react (react-router) will show the proper page depending on URL location.

Comment: why Linked in only showing like this facebook loads perfectly

Comment: how to do redirect to index.html in AWS?

Comment: Without the link to inspect is very hard to say. maybe try the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182920/linkedin-share-url-preview-not-showing-correctly?rq=1

Comment: the page returns a document but with a 404 status code. I believe your s3 bucket is not properly set up with a redirect rule